# Addition and subtraction of large numbers in Java

Tags: java, string, stringbuilder

I have this task , where I am supposed to add or subtract very large numbers (over long long). I need to use String and/or StringBuilder to make it work.

I have some code here but most cases do not work and the subtraction is really buggy.

```
 /** This class contains the method meant to calculate the sum of two large numbers. 
    */
public class SummingLargeNumbers {

  private SummingLargeNumbers() {}

  private static final char ZERO = '0';

  /**
   * Implements addition of two large numbers.
   *
   * @param s1 First number as string.
   * @param s2 Second number as string.
   * @return The answer as a string.
   */
  static String findSum(String s1, String s2) {
    if (s1 == null || s2 == null || s1.equals("") || s2.equals("")) {
      return "";
    }
    if (s1.length() > s2.length()) {
      String temp = s1;
      s1 = s2;
      s2 = temp;
    }
    StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();
    int n1 = s1.length();
    int n2 = s2.length();
    int diff = n2 - n1;
    int denom = 0;
    for (int i = n1 - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
      int sum = ((int) (s1.charAt(i) - ZERO) + (int) (s2.charAt(i + diff) - ZERO) + denom);
      result.append((char) (sum % 10 + ZERO));
      denom = sum / 10;
    }

    for (int i = n2 - n1 - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
      int sum = ((int) (s2.charAt(i) - ZERO) + denom);
      result.append((char) (sum % 10 + ZERO));
      denom = sum / 10;
    }

    if (denom > 0) {
      result.append((char) (denom + ZERO));
    }

    return result.reverse().toString();
  }

  /**
   * Checks whether the first number is smaller than the second.
   *
   * @param s1 First number as a string.
   * @param s2 Second number as a string.
   * @return True if the first number is smaller than the second and false if otherwise.
   */
  static boolean isSmaller(String s1, String s2) {
    int firstLength = s1.length();
    int secondLength = s2.length();

    if (firstLength < secondLength) return true;
    if (secondLength < firstLength) return false;

    for (int i = 0; i < firstLength; i++) {
      if (s1.charAt(i) < s2.charAt(i)) return true;
      else if (s1.charAt(i) > s2.charAt(i)) return false;
    }
    return false;
  }

  /**
   * Implements subtraction of two large numbers.
   *
   * @param s1 First number as a string.
   * @param s2 Second number as a string.
   * @return The answer as a string.
   */
  static String findDiff(String s1, String s2) {
    if (s1 == null || s2 == null || s1.equals("") || s2.equals("")) {
      return "";
    }
    if (isSmaller(s1, s2)) {
      String temp = s1;
      s1 = s2;
      s2 = temp;
    }

    StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();

    int n1 = s1.length();
    int n2 = s2.length();
    int diff = n1 - n2;

    int denom = 0;

    for (int i = n2 - 1; i >= 0; i--) {

      int sum =
          (((int) s1.charAt(i + diff) - (int) '0') - ((int) s2.charAt(i) - (int) '0') - denom);
      if (sum < 0) {
        sum = sum + 10;
        denom = 1;
      } else {
        denom = 0;
      }

      result.append(String.valueOf(sum));
    }

    for (int i = n1 - n2 - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
      if (s1.charAt(i) == '0' && denom > 0) {
        result.append("9");
        continue;
      }
      int sub = (((int) s1.charAt(i) - (int) '0') - denom);
      if (i > 0 || sub > 0) {
        result.append(String.valueOf(sub));
        denom = 0;
      }
    }
    if (result.reverse().indexOf("0") == 0) {
      result.deleteCharAt(0);
    }
    return result.toString();
  }
}
```

I don't really understand where I'm going wrong and now I also have to implement the addition and subtraction into one method and that feels really difficult to me.
I'll be glad if I can get some heads up about this whole thing so I can try and make it work.

For example some cases that don't work are:

> -88131415555612 + 77020304444501 = 11111111111111

Here in this case it should return -11111111111111

> -1021315510 + 2183194 = 1019132316

Here it should also return -1019132316

Mostly cases that have to do with subtraction are wrong.

Comment: I'd suggest having a look at `BigInteger` and either use that class or at least glean some implementation hints from this. As for "where I'm going wrong" - you should step through your code with a debugger and check the values at each step. Provided you understand the algorithm you're implementing you should be able to spot the error.

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/math/BigInteger.html This should do the job for your case.

Comment: @Thomas I am only allowed to use String or StringBuilder for this. 
Regarding the implementation I am using school logic , I calculate the current digits and carry and when that's done I just add the remaining digits to the smaller number.

Comment: I am only allowed to use String or StringBuilder though , that's the issue.

Comment: It might help if you'd provide examples of what doesn't work. Note that we are investing our time to try to make it count.

Answer (score 1):

This looked like an interesting problem, so I gave it a try.  Here are the results from my latest test.

```
123 + 8900 = 9023
123 + 89 = 212
-123 + 893 = 770
-123 + -893 = -1016
123 + -893 = -770
999 + -999 = 0
999 + -997 = 2
-999 + 997 = -2
-88131415555612 + 77020304444501 = -11111111111111
-1021315510 + 2183194 = -1019132316
1021315510 + -2183194 = 1019132316
-1021315510 + -2183194 = -1023498704
```

I had trouble understanding your code.  You had way too many static methods.  In case you're wondering, too many static fields and methods is a bad thing to be avoided.

So, here's how you approach a problem like this.

Break the problem down into smaller and smaller steps until you can code each step.

Here's what I mean:

```
Sum two String numbers
    Return empty string if either String number is null or empty.
    Determine if the first String has a negative sign.
    Determine if the second string has a negative sign.
    If the signs are the same
        Add numbers.
    Else
        Subtract numbers.

Add numbers
    Determine if the first String has a negative sign.
    Strip signs from both numbers.
    Add numbers, starting from the right and going left.
    Append the carry, if any.
    Append the negative sign, if needed.

Subtract numbers
    Order the numbers by absolute value, largest first, then smallest.
    Determine if the largest String has a negative sign.
    Strip signs from both numbers.
    Subtract the smaller from the larger, starting from the right and going left.
    Append the negative sign, if needed.
    Remove leading zeros.
```

Of course, this is much easier to do after you've written the code.

Start small.  I got the same sign addition to work first.  Then I worked on the opposite sign addition (subtraction).

Organize your code like an essay.  Put the most abstract code first, followed by the more detailed code.  The reader of your code should never have to look back at the top to find out how something works.

Here's the complete runnable code.

```
public class SummingLargeNumbers {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SummingLargeNumbers sln = new SummingLargeNumbers();
        
        String s1 = "123";
        String s2 = "8900";
        System.out.println(s1 + " + " + s2 + " = " + sln.findSum(s1, s2));
        
        s1 = "123";
        s2 = "89";
        System.out.println(s1 + " + " + s2 + " = " + sln.findSum(s1, s2));
        
        s1 = "-123";
        s2 = "893";
        System.out.println(s1 + " + " + s2 + " = " + sln.findSum(s1, s2));
        
        s1 = "-123";
        s2 = "-893";
        System.out.println(s1 + " + " + s2 + " = " + sln.findSum(s1, s2));
        
        s1 = "123";
        s2 = "-893";
        System.out.println(s1 + " + " + s2 + " = " + sln.findSum(s1, s2));
        
        s1 = "999";
        s2 = "-999";
        System.out.println(s1 + " + " + s2 + " = " + sln.findSum(s1, s2));
        
        s1 = "999";
        s2 = "-997";
        System.out.println(s1 + " + " + s2 + " = " + sln.findSum(s1, s2));
        
        s1 = "-999";
        s2 = "997";
        System.out.println(s1 + " + " + s2 + " = " + sln.findSum(s1, s2));
        
        s1 = "-88131415555612";
        s2 = "77020304444501";
        System.out.println(s1 + " + " + s2 + " = " + sln.findSum(s1, s2));
        
        s1 = "-1021315510";
        s2 = "2183194";
        System.out.println(s1 + " + " + s2 + " = " + sln.findSum(s1, s2));
        
        s1 = "1021315510";
        s2 = "-2183194";
        System.out.println(s1 + " + " + s2 + " = " + sln.findSum(s1, s2));
        
        s1 = "-1021315510";
        s2 = "-2183194";
        System.out.println(s1 + " + " + s2 + " = " + sln.findSum(s1, s2));
    }
    
    public String findSum(String s1, String s2) {
        if (s1 == null || s2 == null || s1.isEmpty() || s2.isEmpty()) {
            return "";
        }
        
        boolean s1IsNegative = s1.charAt(0) == '-';
        boolean s2IsNegative = s2.charAt(0) == '-';
        
        if (s1IsNegative == s2IsNegative) {
            return addNumbers(s1, s2);
        } else {
            return subtractNumbers(s1, s2);
        }
    }
    
    private String addNumbers(String s1, String s2) {
        boolean s1IsNegative = s1.charAt(0) == '-';
        s1 = stripSign(s1);
        s2 = stripSign(s2);
        int index1 = s1.length() - 1;
        int index2 = s2.length() - 1;
        int carry = 0;
        
        StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
        // Add the two String numbers together;
        while (index1 >= 0 || index2 >= 0) {
            int digit1 = (index1 >= 0) ? convertToInt(s1.charAt(index1--)) : 0;
            int digit2 = (index2 >= 0) ? convertToInt(s2.charAt(index2--)) : 0;
            int sum = digit1 + digit2 + carry;
            carry = sum / 10;
            int digit = sum % 10;
            builder.append(digit);
        }
        
        if (carry > 0) {
            builder.append(carry);
        }
        
        if (s1IsNegative) {
            builder.append('-');
        }
        
        return builder.reverse().toString();
    }
    
    private String subtractNumbers(String s1, String s2) {
        String[] order = orderNumbers(s1, s2);
        String larger = order[0];
        String smaller = order[1];
        boolean largerIsNegative = larger.charAt(0) == '-';
        larger = stripSign(larger);
        smaller = stripSign(smaller);
        int index1 = larger.length() - 1;
        int index2 = smaller.length() - 1;
        int borrow = 0;
        
        StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
        // Subtract the smaller from the larger String number
        while (index1 >= 0 || index2 >= 0) {
            int digit1 = (index1 >= 0) ? convertToInt(larger.charAt(index1--)) : 0;
            int digit2 = (index2 >= 0) ? convertToInt(smaller.charAt(index2--)) : 0;
            int difference = digit1 - digit2 - borrow;
            if (difference < 0) {
                difference += 10;
                borrow = 1;
            } else {
                borrow = 0;
            }
            
            builder.append(difference);
        }
        
        if (largerIsNegative) {
            builder.append('-');
        }
        
        return removeLeadingZeros(builder);
    }
    
    /**
     * This method returns the String numbers in absolute value order.
     * 
     * @param s1 - String number 1
     * @param s2 - String number 2
     * @return - String array consisting of two values. The largest absolute value
     *         is first and the smallest absolute value is second.
     */
    private String[] orderNumbers(String s1, String s2) {
        boolean s1IsNegative = s1.charAt(0) == '-';
        boolean s2IsNegative = s2.charAt(0) == '-';
        s1 = stripSign(s1);
        s2 = stripSign(s2);
        String largest;
        String smallest;
        
        if (s1.length() < s2.length()) {
            largest = (s2IsNegative) ? "-" + s2 : s2;
            smallest = (s1IsNegative) ? "-" + s1 : s1;
        } else if (s1.length() > s2.length()) {
            largest = (s1IsNegative) ? "-" + s1 : s1;
            smallest = (s2IsNegative) ? "-" + s2 : s2;
        } else {
            boolean s1IsLarger = true;
            // Both Strings are the same size.  Find the largest digit,
            // starting from left to right;
            for (int index = 0; index < s1.length(); index++) {
                int digit1 = convertToInt(s1.charAt(index));
                int digit2 = convertToInt(s2.charAt(index));
                if (digit1 < digit2) {
                    s1IsLarger = false;
                    break;
                } else if (digit2 < digit1) {
                    s1IsLarger = true;
                    break;
                }
            }
            
            if (s1IsLarger) {
                largest = (s1IsNegative) ? "-" + s1 : s1;
                smallest = (s2IsNegative) ? "-" + s2 : s2;
            } else {
                largest = (s2IsNegative) ? "-" + s2 : s2;
                smallest = (s1IsNegative) ? "-" + s1 : s1;
            }
        }
        
        String[] output = new String[2];
        output[0] = largest;
        output[1] = smallest;
        
        return output;
    }
    
    private String removeLeadingZeros(StringBuilder builder) {
        int index = builder.length() - 1;
        boolean isNegative = builder.substring(index, index + 1).equals("-");
        
        if (isNegative) {
            builder.delete(index, index + 1);
            index--;
        }
        
        while (index > 0) {
            if (builder.substring(index, index + 1).equals("0")) {
                builder.delete(index, index + 1);
                index--;
            } else {
                break;
            }
        }
        
        if (isNegative) {
            builder.append('-');
        }
        
        return builder.reverse().toString();
    }
    
    private String stripSign(String s) {
        if (s.charAt(0) == '-' || s.charAt(0) == '+') {
            return s.substring(1);
        } else {
            return s;
        }
    }
    
    private int convertToInt(char c) {
        return (int) (c - '0');
    }

}
```

Comment: This solution works , but don't you think it's a bit too complex?

Comment: @Azhdan Yulmi: How would you simplify the code?

Comment: That's the whole question , I feel like there is a shorter implementation this whole thing but I can't seem to code it.
Your solution works perfectly but it has very high Cognitive Complexity and I was wondering if there is a way to simplify it.

Comment: @Azhdan Yulmi: Well, if your code doesn't solve the problem, does it matter that it has a lower Cognitive Complexity?  Which parts of my code have a very high Cognitive Complexity?  Does your measuring tool break it down by method?